# setValue to JFormattedTextField does not show on GUI

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I'm writing a simple loan calculator with gui using swing. I am using DecimalFormat to ensure correct formatting wtih JFormattedTextField .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFormattedTextField loanAmountField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("####.##"));
    JFormattedTextField interestRateField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("####.##"));
    JFormattedTextField yearField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("####.##"));
    JFormattedTextField monthlyPaymentField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("####.##"));


   JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");

    //Calculations based on selection
    int monthlyTest;
    if (monthlyRadioButton.isSelected()){
        monthlyTest = 1;

        calculateButton.addActionListener(new CalculateListener(loanAmountField, interestRateField, yearField, monthlyPaymentField, monthlyTest));
    }
    else{
        monthlyTest = 0;
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new CalculateListener(loanAmountField, interestRateField, yearField, monthlyPaymentField, monthlyTest));

    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to assign a value to loanAmountField, it doesn't update it on my GUI's JFormattedTextField.

```
class CalculateListener implements ActionListener {
public CalculateListener (JFormattedTextField loanAmountField, JFormattedTextField     monthlyPaymentField, JFormattedTextField interestRateField, JFormattedTextField yearField, int monthlyTest)
{
  this.interestRateField = interestRateField;   
  this.yearField = yearField;
  this.loanAmountField = loanAmountField;
  this.monthlyPaymentField = monthlyPaymentField;
  this.monthlyTest = monthlyTest;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
      loanAmountField.setValue(new Double(12.22));
    }

}
```

**How do I display the new value on my GUI JFormattedTextField?**

Comment: Where's the code where you add the listener to the button? My concern is this: it appears that you're setting the text on a JFormattedTextField, but is it the JFormattedTextField that is displayed by the GUI? Are you sure?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not quite sure. I believe I might be creating a new instance and not updating the correct one. However, I don't know how to refer to the one that is being displayed. I updated the code per your request.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You've got an if block in your main method that will depend on a user's selection, but the user won't have selected at the time this code is run. If this is your real code, you need to re-think along the lines of event driven programming. If this is not your real code, then please only show real code here.

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), a very small program that demonstrates your problem and is complete enough to compile and run for us.

Comment: You also have a lot of code present within the main method. Is this how your actual program is coded? If so, change it so that it creates actual GUI objects.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This isn't my complete code. I'm just testing to see if I can display the correct value on my GUI before I start writing the calculations.

Comment: that's a good thing to do. Consider creating a small compilable testable bit of code that we can run and modify and hopefully fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), I mean something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCalculatorListener extends JPanel {
   private JFormattedTextField loanAmountField = new JFormattedTextField(
         NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());

   public TestCalculatorListener() {
      loanAmountField.setColumns(8);
      loanAmountField.setEditable(false);
      loanAmountField.setFocusable(false);
      add(loanAmountField);
      add(new JButton(new CalculateListener(loanAmountField)));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestCalculatorListener mainPanel = new TestCalculatorListener();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestCalculatorListener");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

   private class CalculateListener extends AbstractAction {
      private JFormattedTextField loanAmountField;

      public CalculateListener(JFormattedTextField loanAmountField) {
         super("Calculate");
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_C);
         this.loanAmountField = loanAmountField;
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
         loanAmountField.setValue(new Double(12.22));
      }

   }
}
```

Which shows that at least some of the code you've posted works fine.

Comment: Was able to fix this problem. I'll try to post an SSCCE next time :)